# Relation between convergence of pmfs, in distribution and in total variation for discrete distributions?

Tags: probability-theory

For a sequence of discrete probability distributions, are following convergence modes equivalent:

- pointwise convergence of their pmfs,
- convergence in distribution (assuming the distributions are defined on $\mathbb Z$),
- convergence in total variation
- [weak convergence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_measures#Weak_convergence_of_measures)(how is it defined for discrete distributions?)?

Consider the above questions when the sample space is countably infinite.

When it is finite, the first three are equivalent, if I am correct.

Thanks and regards!

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: @Did: I have tried: when the sample space is finite, the first three are equivalent, because total variation norm can be represented as sup norm on the pmf. I am not sure about countable sample space.